# Autosave reactive forms

Tags: javascript, form, event-handling, angular-2+, databinding

I'm building an autosave for a data driven form on Angular.

Here is our code snippet:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        enabled: [false],
    });

    this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        withLatestFrom(this.form.statusChanges.pipe(filter(status => status === 'VALID')))
    ).subscribe((value) => console.log('We could autosave!', value[0], 'status', value[1]));

}
```

It works but I wonder if it's optimal to use the `statusChanges`.

Indeed we could use the `valid` property instead:

```
this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(500)
).subscribe((value) => {
    if (this.form.valid) {
        console.log('We could autosave!', value);
    }
});
```

What would be the most reliable/optimal method?